# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) getting image to display on thumbnail

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to display BitMapImage on `ImageView` I was able to get Camera to work, but accessing image from directory keeps giving me 
`E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/15126: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

My code is below

```
    private void openImageIntent(){

    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "amfb" + File.separator);
    root.mkdir();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam){
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    //FileSystem
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

And in `onActivityForResult` I did the check for result and set my image

```
selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                Log.d("ImageURI", selectedImageUri.toString());
                // /Bitmap factory
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                // images
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageUri.getPath());
                preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did solve my problem by doing this in my `onActivityForResult`

```java
selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
Log.d("ImageURI", selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
// Bitmap factory
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
// downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger images
options.inSampleSize = 8;
try {
    InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    Log.d("ImageURI", input.toString());
    preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```